# Intellij Maven settings keep resetting

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ my Maven settings, such as

- Maven home path
- Local repository (override checked) and
- VM options for importer

keep getting changed in regular intervals without me doing anything. Basically I have to reset those settings once a day, have you guys had any similiar problems?

(IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2 (Ultimate Edition), Maven 3)

Comment: These settings are stored in `.idea/workspace.xml` file inside the project under the `<component name="MavenImportPreferences">` node. Make sure this file is not removed/overwritten, for example, when you switch branches or git reset.

Comment: What being reset? The local repository path is configure either as default or based on a given `setting.xml` in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you. I haven't changed branches or anything, but I will monitor when exactly it happens.

Comment: @khmarbaise The local repository can be overwritten in the settings instead of taking the one from settings.xml

Comment: Yes of course you can but the question is: Why? For what purpose?